# error click on a line cause by the filter

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

Current behavior:
I can select an item from the list by clicking on the button and access the information about this item.
But when the filter is applied and I click on the button it is the information of another item that I get.

Behavior wish:
I would like to access the information of an item even if the filter is applied.

Probable cause:
I think the error is due to changing the size of the array, when the filter is applying the size decreases so index will probably be smaller than its index in UserList.

Help me found a solution.

HTML- filter

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term">
```

HTML loop

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of usersList | myfilter:term, let i = index">
        <td> {{user.uid}} </td>
        <td> {{user.nom}} </td>
        <td> {{user.prenom}} </td>
        <td> {{user.tel}} </td>
        <td> {{user.type}} </td>
        <td> {{user.email}} </td>
        <td> {{user.dati}} </td>
        <td> <button (click)="onViewUser(id=this.usersList[i].uid)" class="btn btn-primary"> Rôle</button> <button class="btn btn-success" > Modifier </button> </td>
    </tr>
```

myfilter.ts

```
transform(ninjas: any, term: any): any {  
   if(term === undefined) return ninjas;
   return ninjas.filter(function(ninja){
   return ninja.nom.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) ||
     ninja.prenom.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) ||
     ninja.tel.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) ||
     ninja.email.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) ||
     ninja.dati.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) ||
     ninja.type.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())     
   });
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand anything. What's the desired behavior, and what's the actual behavior?

Comment: show all relevant sections of the code. We don't know how your filter gets applied on to your list and such!

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your selection code from:

`onViewUser(id=this.usersList[i].uid)`

to

`onViewUser(user?.uid)`